# node.js - Jade template's for loop

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a jade template (on node.js server). I have the following for loop to test with and the console.log prints that for loop index (value of x) is undefined.

What is the wrong with my statement?

```
          for (var x = 2; x < 4; x++) 
            - console.log('current x =' + x);
```

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to put `- ` before `for`.

Comment: @TimCooper, if I put -  then it shows me a "error at new JS_Parse_Error"

Comment: Ensure that your indentation is correct.  You template should look like [this](http://pastebin.com/SUpswxUs).

Comment: your code works, mine doesnt....dont know whats the difference...thx anyways